# Routing for FormView Class

Tags: python, django

I have `django_test` project and `defapp` application in it.

I want to access form.html which MyView makes,

I am still confused about routing.

I can access `localhost/defapp/` and show  `Hello, World`

However how can I access the MyView class and show `form.html`?

in `django_test/urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include,url

urlpatterns = [
    path('defapp/', include('defapp.urls')),
    url(r'^s3direct/', include('s3direct.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

in `defapp/views.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
 
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

in `defapp/views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import FormView
from .forms import S3DirectUploadForm

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world.")
class MyView(FormView):
    template_name = 'form.html'
    form_class = S3DirectUploadForm
```

in `defapp/template/form.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>s3direct</title>
    {{ form.media }}
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to do? I don't understand "how can I access the MyView class?".

Comment: I updated the article more precise explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to know how to wire up a class based view in the urlconf, please checkout these [docs on class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/#usage-in-your-urlconf).

> The most direct way to use generic views is to create them directly in your URLconf. If you’re only changing a few attributes on a class-based view, you can pass them into the as_view() method call itself:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
]
```

Additionally, the docs on [`as_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) may prove helpful.

Comment: @schilingt. I understand the meaning of as_view. It works. thank you very much!